# C#/XAML Windows 8 AppBar by command?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I apologize if this is a simple question. I'm very new to XAML, and I'm trying to understand app development more.

Basically, I have a section on the bottom of the display reserved for a pop-up AppBar. From what I understand, this pops up on an edge swipe, but I'd like to use some sort of a call to bring it up. This way I can have various varieties of the AppBar pop-up when the situation calls for it.

How would I go about accomplishing this?
OR, is there another approach that might work better?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: @MZetko answer applies to Windows 8. Mine applies to Windows Phone. You've used both tags in your question. Please be sure to specify which platform you're referring to, as this will affect the correctness of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page has a `BottomAppBar` property (`<Page.BottomAppBar>`). Here you can enter a `AppBar` control and inside of it any XAML you want. Then you can show and hide anything through the `Visiblity` property from code. So - you can for example add two `Grid`controls in the `AppBar` and always display one of them.

Comment: This is not supported by Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create multiple AppBars for use on the same page, you'll have to do so in the code behind. See this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431786(v=vs.105).aspx

Once you've created them, set the IsVisible property to true/false to show/hide them.

Comment: This seems to apply to Windows Phone, but I'm not sure you can follow the same steps for Windows 8.